# Not needed ports are opened on EKS security group

Tags: security, amazon-eks, group

A EKS cluster is deployed on AWS. There is a security group **eks-cluster-sg-my-cluster-uniqueID** created for the EKS cluster. This EKS cluster has different namespaces wherein 2 different applications say app1 and app2 are installed on 2 different namespaces. App1 has added a inbound rule on port 8000 on SG **eks-cluster-sg-my-cluster-uniqueID**. App2 uses the following service and ingress rule in the helm values.yml file

```
service:
  type: NodePort
  port: 80
  targetPort: xxxx

ingress:
  enabled: true
  ingressClassName: alb
  annotations: 
      #kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /healthz
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: '443'
```

When the above ingress rule is deployed, it does not add a new inbound rule in **eks-cluster-sg-my-cluster-uniqueID** instead it will add a inbound rule `8000-30777`, where 30777 is the nodeport because of the above service. If I remove the above ingress rule and deploy via helm upgrade, it will remove the entry `8000-30777` and only keep `8000`. What I do not understand why is it adding `8000-30777` to the SG? Can anybody help me in understanding this